# A question about the model structure that allows you to put data vertically in a data grid

Tags: xamarin.android

| Title | A | B | c |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Section | Net Revenue | ZB | B Securities |
| LineItem | Net Revenue | TU | Cantor Fitzgerald |
| Broker Code | Cost of Goods Sold | ZB | B Securities |
| Broker Name | Cost of Goods Sold | TU | Cantor Fitzgerald |

```
bindinglist<data> dataCollection = new bindinglist<data>();
data = new data()
{ 
   title = section,
   A = LineItem     ,
   B = Broker Code,
   C = Broker Name 
}
```

I am trying to implement a table with this structure.
It is a structure in which header and data are exchanged in a general table.
I want to implement a model to bind to this datagrid. I don't know what  to do.

I want a model structure where I can put the data vertically in the data grid. Thanks a lot for your advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to achieve [this effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/goohi.jpg)? Each column is a set of data. If so, you can try the following code.

Page.xaml:

```
<StackLayout>
    <Grid x:Name="productGrid">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Label Grid.Row="0" Text="Title" FontAttributes="Bold" VerticalOptions="Center" />
        <Label Grid.Row="1" Text="Section" FontAttributes="Bold" VerticalOptions="Center" />
        <Label Grid.Row="2" Text="LineItem" FontAttributes="Bold" VerticalOptions="Center" />
        <Label Grid.Row="3" Text="BrokerCode" FontAttributes="Bold" VerticalOptions="Center" />
        <Label Grid.Row="4" Text="BrokerName" FontAttributes="Bold" VerticalOptions="Center" />
    </Grid>
</StackLayout>
```

Page.xaml.cs:

```
public partial class Page2 : ContentPage
{
    List<Data> Datas = new List<Data>()
    {
       new Data(){ Title="title1", Section="section1",LineItem="lineItem1",BrokerCode="brokerC1",BrokerName="brokerN1"},
       new Data(){ Title="title2", Section="section2",LineItem="lineItem2",BrokerCode="brokerC2",BrokerName="brokerN2"},
       new Data(){ Title="title3", Section="section3",LineItem="lineItem3",BrokerCode="brokerC3",BrokerName="brokerN3"},
       new Data(){ Title="title4", Section="section4",LineItem="lineItem4",BrokerCode="brokerC4",BrokerName="brokerN4"},
    };
    public Page2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        CreateDummyGrids();
    }
    public void CreateDummyGrids()
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < Datas.Count; i++)
        {
            productGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition());
        }

        for (int columnIndex = 1; columnIndex <= Datas.Count; columnIndex++)
        {
            for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < Datas[0].GetType().GetProperties().Length; rowIndex++)
            {
                switch (rowIndex)
                {
                    case 0:
                        var label0 = new Label
                        {
                            Text = Datas[columnIndex - 1].Title,
                            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center
                        };
                        productGrid.Children.Add(label0, columnIndex, rowIndex);
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        var label1 = new Label
                        {
                            Text = Datas[columnIndex - 1].Section,
                            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
                        };
                        productGrid.Children.Add(label1, columnIndex, rowIndex);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        var label2 = new Label
                        {
                            Text = Datas[columnIndex - 1].LineItem,
                            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
                        };
                        productGrid.Children.Add(label2, columnIndex, rowIndex);
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        var label3 = new Label
                        {
                            Text = Datas[columnIndex - 1].BrokerCode,
                            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
                        };
                        productGrid.Children.Add(label3, columnIndex, rowIndex);
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        var label4 = new Label
                        {
                            Text = Datas[columnIndex - 1].BrokerName,
                            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
                        };
                        productGrid.Children.Add(label4, columnIndex, rowIndex);
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```